# How do I install Python packages in Google's Colab?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, setup.py

In a project, I have e.g. two different packages, How can I use the setup.py to install these two packages in the Google's Colab, so that I can import the packages?

Answer (score 154):

You can use `!setup.py install` to do that.

Colab is just like a Jupyter notebook. Therefore, we can use the `!` operator here to install any package in Colab. What `!` actually does is, *it tells the notebook cell that this line is not a Python code, its a command line script*. So, to run any command line script in Colab, just add a `!` **preceding** the line.

For example: `!pip install tensorflow`. This will treat that line (here `pip install tensorflow`) as a command prompt line and not some Python code. However, if you do this without adding the `!` preceding the line, it'll throw up an error saying "invalid syntax".

But keep in mind that **you'll have to upload the `setup.py` file to your drive** before doing this (preferably into the same folder where your notebook is).

*Hope this answers your question :)*

Comment: your answer would be easier to read if it weren't split into a list

Comment: I just ran `!setup.py install` and it shows `/bin/bash: setup.py: command not found`. I have uploaded the whole package and the setup.py file exists in the same folder as the notebook

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Did you try `!python setup.py install`?

Comment: It seems that it is not possible to directly provide url of setup.py from github.

Comment: I do not understand the difference between !pip and pip, both are giving same results i.e., installing the package without any error, mind if someone could clear that?

Comment: @keramat: it is possible to install Python packages from GitHub, but not by referring to its `setup.py`. Rather, to install e.g. `scipy` use: `!pip install git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git`. The gist here is to use `git+https` in the URL. `pip` will try to find `setup.py` in the URL and install as usual.

Answer (score 81):

A better, more modern, answer to this question is to use the `%pip` magic, like:

```
%pip install scipy
```

That will automatically use the correct Python version. Using `!pip` might be tied to a different version of Python, and then you might not find the package after installing it.

And in colab, the magic gives a nice message and button if it detects that you need to restart the runtime if pip updated a packaging you have already imported.

BTW, there is also a `%conda` magic for doing the same with conda.

Answer (score 60):

Let's say you want to install scipy. Here is the code to install it:

```
!pip install scipy
```

If that doesn't work, try this

```
%pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 27):

Joining the party late, but just as a complement, I ran into some problems with Seaborn not so long ago, because CoLab installed a version with !pip that wasn't updated. In my specific case, I couldn't use Scatterplot, for example. The answer to this is below:

**To install the module, all you need is:**

```
!pip install seaborn
```

**To upgrade it to the most updated version:**

```
!pip install --upgrade seaborn
```

**If you want to install a specific version**

```
!pip install seaborn==0.9.0
```

I believe all the [rules common to pip](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) apply normally, so that pretty much should work.

Comment: This is the clearest, easiest to read answer here, it needs more upvotes!

Answer (score 4):

> To import a library that's not in Colaboratory by default, you can use `!pip install` or `!apt-get install`.
>
> ```py
> !pip install matplotlib-venn
> ```

- [Library Import Snippets](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb) (colab.research.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload setup.py to drive.
2. Mount the drive.
3. Get the path of setup.py.
4. !python PATH install.