# Colab error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, geopandas

When I try to import geopandas package in "Google Colaboratory" I got the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'".

I will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try pip install geopandas?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colaboratory comes with some non-base-Python packages "pre-installed"/already available for import. It doesn't include every single package however. For packages that aren't already included, like `geopandas`, you need to add a cell for installing the package:

```
% pip install geopandas
```

Run this cell before any cells where you want to import/use geopandas.

See also [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab) (especially the answer by Doug Blank, a bit further down).

Answer (score 1):

Check if geopandas is installed

```
>>> import sys
>>> 'geopandas' in sys.modules
```

To install the released version, you can use pip (in Google Colab, do not forget to include character ! before pip):

```
!pip install geopandas
```

Here is the notebook with only installing Gdal, geopandas and descartes to work ploting and spatial join.
[Geopandas Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tSmJmjD3sTI31Cg1UCIKiE10dBUmWUG7#scrollTo=3z2rlY3LkQX9)

Answer (score 0):

Try running `!pip install geopandas` in a new cell.
Don't forget the `!` Exclamation mark.

**Note:**
This method works for other libraries too.
Simply `!pip install 'package_name'`

If you are running Python on your local machine, then open up Command Line and type        `pip install 'package_name'` to install a package.