# How to deploy or share your python program to friends

Tags: python, deployment

I wanted to share my python program to my friends but the problem is they will have to install python first then all the libraries which I used in order to run my program and it might be hard to do so as I have used too many libraries like 15-20 something.

MY Questions:-
Q1. How can I share my python program without making them install so much stuff?
Q2. Is there any other language on which it could be done?

Thank you.

Regards

Comment: Regarding Q2, a static webpage (HTML/CSS/JS) using simple JavaScript is very easy to show to friends. Or maybe an Android/iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Colab**

You can write your python program in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com) and then share the notebook with others to run.

It's free to use and your dependencies can be imported or installed based on the information from this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab).

**Streamlit**

[Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) allows you to build custom web apps using python that are shareable. It's marketed use is for data science and machine learning python projects. You should check their website to see if it satisfies your specific needs.

Comment: what if I want to release this program in market ?

Comment: Hey Malay, I would need more information about your use case. It sounded like you wanted to share a python program for friends to review. Google colab works well for that. If you are asking for how to productionize a python program into an application, then a limited version of this can be done with Streamlit. For proper deployment, I would look into how progressive web apps are made. You might have to use frameworks such as Flask and FastAPI, as well as hosting sites such as Heroku, AWS, etc. Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

## `repl.it`

On the website `repl.it` you can create public Python projects which can even include PyPI dependencies. The user can then run and edit them, for example here: https://replit.com/@TedTaras/Monster-Hunter. Projects are public by default, private ones cost extra.