# Cannot upgrade library to specific version on Google Colab (scipy version 1.8.0)

Tags: python, pip, scipy, google-colaboratory

There was a function added to one of the latest versions of Scipy. I want to use this version on a Google Colab notebook but I cannot upgrade Scipy to the version I need.

Here's what I tried based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab) and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226311/installing-specific-package-version-with-pip):

```py
!pip install scipy==1.8.0
```

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy==1.8.0 (from versions: 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0rc2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0rc2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0rc2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy==1.8.0

According to the [scipy documentation](https://scipy.org/), version 1.8.0 was released on February this year. How come I can't upgrade to version 1.8.0 on Google Colab?

I was able to upgrade to this version with a simple `pip install scipy --upgrade` on my local computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google colab runs on Python 3.7, however SciPy 1.8.0 requires at least Python 3.8

[image: google colab python version]

According to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.8.0.html,

> This release requires Python 3.8+ and NumPy 1.17.3 or greater.