# Having some problem with filtering data for single cell RNA sequencing

Tags: python, rna-seq, sequencing

Currently I am trying to filter some data for single cell RNA sequencing, and this process requires the use of python. I am trying to run the following codes and I am facing some errors.

```
%pylab inline

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

from SCCAF import *
```

The image of the error message is attached with this post.

error message

[image: 1]

I would also like to say that I have elementary knowledge in working with python, so it can be some issue from my side that I am not able to solve. Also currently I am using google colab to run this code. Can any one please me with this problem.

I have tried installing SCAAF and scanpy using pip install, but still no progress.

Comment: You are missing SCCAF package. You should install SCAAF package. Common way is with `pip install`. You said you done it... check if you done it the proper way, I never used Google Collab, so maybe you installed the package in a wrong location, or with a wrong procedure.

Comment: Try with `%pip install SCCAF` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab)

Comment: This is the first time for me using python and I have only elementary knowledge. I can share the file with the code. Can you please try running it explain me in brief about the whole process?

Comment: link for the code files- https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1GxKSOTj8Nchm4lPqg-YBXDOfceuQ2tdV       Can you please run the scripts by yourself and help me running the whole process.

Comment: Sorry, I almost never used notebooks, so I won't be of much help here. My advice is only based on my Python experience and Google/SO help. Also, your issue does not seem related to the code but to your environment, so checking your code won't be of much help.