# TensorFlow object detection TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-science, tensorflow2.0, object-detection

I have been experimenting trying to solve it for weeks. I am using Google [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Industry_adoption) since I got a MacBook Pro with an [Apple chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_M1) that is not supported by TensorFlow. Here is the Google Colaboratory link with commenting access.  [Click here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yAr_6q-zEoT-ohdg3ma3j52TDOgd4GBE?usp=sharing).

I have tried using older versions of TensorFlow, but nothing changed, I have the TensorFlow record and training pipeline files ready.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking about one of the Tensorflow requirements, you might need to install some software to get it working.

Comment: No, I need to solve the error. Althought tensorRT is installed. 
2023-04-18 10:43:29.342280: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>

Comment: I am facing the same problem, have you solved it @Ali?

Comment: Has anyone had this problem on AWS?

Comment: I faced the same problem today, then I used this trick to get out: 1、pip/pip3 install tensorrt 2、put "import tensorrt" into your .py file where tensorflow is used. Yes, even if you don't use it in your code, import it. Then you will still get the warning: Could not find TensorRT, but now gpu is used!  (if it doesn't work, try to import tensorrt before tensorflow) Don't ask me why it works, I don't know either, I saw it from a Chinese web page: 
 https://blog.csdn.net/miles2007/article/details/132561059. (PS: I'm using keras 3.1.1, and tensorflow 2.16.1)

Answer (score 26):

Try to install `pip install tensorrt`.

Perhaps you need to read this> [How do I install Python packages in Google's Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342408/how-do-i-install-python-packages-in-googles-colab)

And check if a GPU is allocated with google colab.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now I have one more thing to experiment with rather than being completely lost haha, but sadly I still have the same error. 
Runtime is set on GPU T4. 

2023-04-18 10:43:29.342280:tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24, in <module>

Comment: check the tensorflow version and the tensor rt version.

Comment: Name: tensorrt
Version: 8.6.0
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.12.0
Are they compatible ?

Comment: try to reinstall tensorflow and play around...

Comment: I have already tried it few time, thank you.

Comment: cant you create a google colab environment and share it for us?

Comment: pip install nvidia-pyindex
pip install nvidia-tensorrt

or 

`
pip3 install tensorrt-5.0.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
pip3 install pycuda 
`

pip is usally for python2 and pip3 is python3

Comment: here is the google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yAr_6q-zEoT-ohdg3ma3j52TDOgd4GBE?usp=sharing. Thank you i will try it now.

Comment: from the `oontrib` errors I would say that you don't have the exact tensorflow version number. Contrib was used in an earlier version and you install the latest tensorflow version.