# How can I install node 14.+ on Google Collab

Tags: python, node.js, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install node 14 on Google Colab. but it keeps installing node 10.19. My project needs node 14. I am using this command to install it:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

Is there a way to install Node 14 on google collab?

Thank you

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61212861/9714255

Answer (score 2):

Please, follow this:

[Source](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)

```bash
!dpkg --configure -a
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg
!sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
!curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg
!NODE_MAJOR=18 && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
!sudo apt-get update
# RUN the following commented lines to remove the previous installed nodejs (avoid conflict error)
#!sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq nodejs
#!sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode-dev
#!sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libnode72:amd64
!sudo apt-get install nodejs -y
```